# Impala - Working hours between two dates in impala

Tags: datetime, impala

I have two time stamps @starttimestamp and @endtimestamp. How to calculate number of working hours between these two
Working hours is defined below:
Mon- Thursday (9:00-17:00)
Friday (9:00-13:00)

Have to work in impala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think i found a better solution.

1. we will create a series of numbers using a large table. You can get a time dimension type table too. Make it doenst get truncated. I am using a large table from my db.
   Use this series to generate a date range between start and end date.

```
date_add (t.start_date,rs.uniqueid) -- create range of dates
join (select row_number() over ( order by mycol) as uniqueid  -- create range of unique ids
from  largetab) rs 
where end_date >=date_add (t.start_date,rs.uniqueid)
```

2. Then we will calculate total hour difference between the timestamp using unix timestamp considering date and time.
   `unix_timestamp(endtimestamp - starttimestamp )`
3. Exclude non working hours like 16hours on M-T, 20hours on F, 24hours on S-S.

```
case when  dayofweek ( dday) in (1,7) then 24 
         when dayofweek ( dday) =5 then 20 
         else 16 end as non work hours
```

Here is complete SQL.

```
select 
end_date, start_date, 
diff_in_hr - sum(case when  dayofweek ( dday) in (1,7) then 24 
         when dayofweek ( dday) =5 then 20 
         else 16 end ) total_workhrs

from (
select  (unix_timestamp(end_date)- unix_timestamp(start_date))/3600 as diff_in_hr , end_date, start_date,date_add (t.start_date,rs.uniqueid)   as dDay
from    tdate t 
join (select row_number() over ( order by mycol) as uniqueid from  largetab) rs
where end_date >=date_add (t.start_date,rs.uniqueid) 
)rs2
group by 1,2,diff_in_hr
```

Comment: Hi Koushik, thank you for this. But usually the two dates are different. If a task is opened on 1/09/2022 and closed on 15/09/2022. I would like to know how many working hours elapsed in between. And working hours are always  Mon- Thursday (9:00-17:00) Friday (9:00-13:00)

Comment: updated the answer with consideration of absolute date and time differnces... can you pls check?